# XCode4 - doesn't allow to drag&copy group to group

Tags: ios, ios4, drag-and-drop, xcode4, copy

I have opened two projects side by side.

I am trying to drag & drop files including project groups from oneProject to another.

XCode4 doesn't copy at all ( It doen't copy groups :( ).
What should we do to copy files including groups of it ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had to do this.  It's a little labor intensive but if you've managed your physical file structure it's not too bad.  What I did was to…

- create the folders in the new project to be the same as the old project
- right-click the folder into which you want to move your files and select "Add Files to [My Project]"
- Navigate to the existing files in the other project that need to go under this folder and select them
- Ensure the "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)" is checked
- Click Add.

This will copy the files into the new project folder and add them to the selected folder in Xcode.  This is not a perfect way to copy these files since you cannot specifically point to any physical folder that you wish.

If you need to have files in specific physical folder I have had luck with selecting the file, then delete, then select Remove References Only, Move the file(s) to the correct folder, then add the file(s) back in.

Hope this helps,
Rob

Comment: I already knew this way of copying groups. XCode3 allows direct drag&Drop copy facility including groups. Isn't there any way to do same in XCode4 ? & Thanks for your answer Dude @Rob.

Comment: That's a good question.  There are still a few things that Xcode 3 can do that we're still waiting for in Xcode 4.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best workaround I've found:

- Create a new **Workspace**
- **Add the projects** where you want to copy groups from one to the other
- **Copy groups between projects!**

No need to keep the workspace around afterwards as it's just a pretty dumb container and doesn't affect the projects themselves.